# The issue with Laravel Routing

Tags: php, laravel

Version of Apache: Apache/2.4.4 (Win32) OpenSSL/0.9.8y PHP/5.4.19

Authors.php can be found in the Controllers folder.

```
<?php

class AuthorsController extends BaseController {

    public $restful = true;

    public function getIndex () {
        return View::make('authors.index');
    }
}

?>
```

within routes.php

```
<?php 

//Route::get('authors', 'AuthorsController@getIndex');
Route::get('authors', array('uses' => 'authors@index'));

?>
```

When I try to access the browser: localhost/laravel/public/, the first page displays: You have arrived.

However, when I try to pass the parameter authors in the browser: localhost/laravel/public/authors, it fails.

its display: Something appears to have gone wrong. What is the issue with the Laravel framework?

Comment: Can you turn on debugging and paste the error msg?

Comment: how debugger turn on ? sorry i am beginner

Comment: `/app/config/app.php` make sure `'debug' => true` is set

Comment: ReflectionException (-1) 
Class AuthorsController does not exist

Comment: E:\Web\xampp\htdocs\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\ControllerInspector.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think

```
composer dump-autoload
```

may help.

Answer (score 2):

**Update:**

the problem is file name in your controllers folder: rename `authors.php` to `AuthorsController.php`.

Remember: controller file name must match controller class name itself, this is crucial for auto loading. example: `SomeController` must reside in `SomeController.php`, this applies to any class no matter it's controller or other class file, for laravel, or any other framework (anyway this is the only right way doing it).

**Old:**

Try this:

```
Route::get('public/authors', 'AuthorsController@getIndex');
```

Also problem maybe resides in your url rewrites, if you can show it too.

I think you have just installed laravel now.
Anyway make sure: you have `.htaccess` file included in the document root, and move index file from `public` folder to root and change pathes accordingly, in that case

```
Route::get('authors', 'AuthorsController@getIndex');
```

will work.

Comment: I am sure that your solution is correct to solve his error. He mismatch controller name and class name.

Answer (score 2):

in routes.php

```
Route::get('/authors/', 'AuthorsController@index');
```

in AuthorsControllers

```
<?php

class AuthorsController extends BaseController
{    
public function index()
{
    return View::make('authors.index');
}
//some more function goes here 
}
```

make sure you have a folder named authors if you still find issues open app/storage/logs/laravel.log file clear it and save it and again visit localhost/laravel/public/authors in your browser and then post the result of laravel.log here

Comment: [2014-09-08 10:42:17] production.ERROR: exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class AuthorsController does not exist' in E:\Web\xampp\htdocs\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\ControllerInspector.php:28
Stack trace:
#0 E:\Web\xampp\htdocs\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\ControllerInspector.php(28): ReflectionClass->__construct('AuthorsControll...')
#1 E:\Web\xampp\htdocs\laravel\bootstrap\compiled.php(4719): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerInspector->getRoutable('AuthorsControll...', '/authors') : more charactors not allow ???

Comment: Delete your current authors.php and in your command prompt navigate to laravel installation directory and run php artisan controller:make AuthorController

Comment: yes i delete authors.php and make new file with AuthorControll.php with same name class as file name but problem still remain ?

Answer (score 1):

Modify

```
Route::get('authors', array('uses' => 'authors@index'));
```

to

```
Route::controller('/authors', 'AuthorsController');
```

Using the `controller` method is more powerful as it will allow you to use `get` and `post` requests in your controller whilst keeping your `routes.php` file clean.

Comment: Can you update your answer with error messages your are getting.

Comment: yes, error : ReflectionException (-1) 
Class AuthorsController does not exist, when i try to upload error image its asking for 10 reputations.

Comment: use postimage.org to upload images